# Chance that a vector of observations come from one distribution versus others

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, model-selection

My question relates directly to the question at [Test to what population an observation came from](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71064/test-to-see-what-population-an-observation-came-from) but I would like to know how to update the information about each possible distribution given successive observations.

Put simply, if, after having made the first observation $x_1$, I calculate for each relevant distribution $N(\mu_1, \sigma^2), N(\mu_2, \sigma^2), \ldots N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$ the probability that observation $x_1$ came from that distribution, how can I update those probabilities in the light of succeeding observations $x_2, x_3, \ldots$ ? I should add that, in the particular case I'm interested in, the $i$ different distributions have equal a-priori likelihood and represent an exhaustive list of possibilities.